JPA relationShip ManyToOne from embedded to embeddable
I have next class embeddable:
@Data
@Embeddable
public class JobOrderViewPK2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "IS_COUNCIL")
    Boolean isCouncil;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_GENERAL_ID")
    private Long addressGeneralId;

That is embedded by:
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOB_ORDER_VIEW", schema = "avt")
@Data
public class JobOrderViewEntity2
    implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private JobOrderViewPK2 id;

    @Column(name = "COMMENTS")
    private String comments;

    @Column(name = "JOB_ORDER_PARENT_ID")
    private Long jobOrderParentId;
    ...


And I want to add relationSheep ManyToOne from jobOrderParentId to id on JobOrderViewEntity2.
But trying:
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOB_ORDER_VIEW", schema = "avt")
@Data
public class JobOrderViewEntity2
    implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private JobOrderViewPK2 id;

    @Column(name = "COMMENTS")
    private String comments;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ORDER_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private JobOrderViewEntity2 jobOrderParent;
    ...


Returns error of wrong number of column.
And trying this:
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ORDER_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id.id")
    private JobOrderViewEntity2 jobOrderParent;
...

Returns error of supertables and secondary tables.
Can I do what I'm trying?


"referencedColumnName = "id.id" - id.id ? That looks wrong.
